# How to copy global functions between lua_State

Tags: lua

I need to copy a global function in a `lua_State` to a new `lua_State`, because this function will be called in multiple threads, I need to assign `lua_State` to each thread separately

Here is the simplified code, I want to implement TODO

```cpp
lua_State *La = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(La);
        
luaL_dostring(La, "x = 10");
luaL_dostring(La, "function hello() print(x) end");
lua_getglobal(La, "hello");
lua_call(La, 0, 0); // Expected to print 10
        
lua_State *Lb = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(Lb);
        
// TODO: copy La hello to Lb hello
        
lua_getglobal(Lb, "hello");
lua_call(Lb, 0, 0); // Expected to print nil
        
lua_close(La);
lua_close(Lb);
```

Comment: Lua is not designed to be multithreaded, if you need a funtion to be called in multiple lua_State, add a C function to them.

Comment: @shingo  my current solution is to re-use luaL_dofile in each thread

Comment: Just "sharing" a function is not possible in the general case. I suppose sometimes it can be done using `string.dump` (in the case of pure functions), but when you have upvalues (including the environment `_ENV`), you'd get thread-unsafe code if you were able to share a function between states.

Comment: Is there any problem with the solution?